# Live values in LLVM

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, compiler-theory

Suppose I have in my CFG (among others) two basic blocks A and B, with an edge from A to B. I need to do the following:

- get the set S of live values across
  that edge (it can be an
  overapproximation, i.e. it might
  contain values that are not live
  anymore)
- map each of them to another
  value (S->S')
- replace - in B and its
  successors - all the uses of values
  in S with the mapped values (S')

Does LLVM provide an easy way to do the first and third points (because I can't seem to be able to find it)? If not, do you have any suggestions about how to do it?

note: crossposted on the LLVM mailing list

Comment: sorry, but what are 'live values'?

Comment: @lurscher in SSA a value (you could also call it "variable" but it would be incorrect, since in SSA you can't change its content after the definition) is said to be live if it will be used again in the following instructions.

Comment: most of these SSA registers are pruned after the optimization passes, so i guess the answer of your question depends largely if you want those sets after or before the optimization passes happen

Answer (score 3):

I do not have clear answer to your question, but director to follow, that came to my mind. I hope it will help you in some way.

First, I would check out ["Iterating over the Instructions in a BasicBlock"](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#iterate_basicblock) and ["Iterating over def-use & use-def chains" from LLVM Programmers Manual](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#iterate_chains). It gives an idea how to iterate over instructions in basic block and users of this value.

As you need to know living values across the edge, I would check out ["Iterating over the BasicBlocks in a Function"](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#iterate_function), and try to determine where users (over ech you iterate) are placed, for example with [const BasicBlock* llvm::Instruction::getParent()const](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html#a9cd49851904f15060edb782ef4dd1b2d).

If information, where users are placed is not enough, you might like to take advantage of [dominators and postdominators analysis], check out :

- [LLVM analysis passes](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#analyses) like "-domtree""postdom" etc ;
- [bool llvm::DominatorTree::dominates (const BasicBlock *A, const BasicBlock *B) const](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DominatorTree.html#af42bc0a83365749625cea5a0a720c145)
- [bool DominatorTree::dominates (const Instruction *A, const Instruction *B) const](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DominatorTree.html#a2cbe2ab0b5adadbf185ccacd336c3d3b)

This might help you determine dominance relation between blocks or instructions, what might help you with creation of your sets.